# Populate Products in Custom Endpoint for Woocommerce My Account Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, dashboard, account

I am trying to customize the MY ACCOUNT dashboard on WOOCOMMERCE and I was able to create a "custom endpoint" but I need to fill it with the product on the site, getting rid of the "account data info" as well. It shouldn't be showing anything at all with the code I am using.

If anyone can help me out I'd be very appreciative.

[dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hoAV.jpg)

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_new_item_endpoint');

/**
 * Register New Endpoint.
 *
 * @return void.
 */
function register_new_item_endpoint() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'narcx-products', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
}


add_filter( 'query_vars', 'new_item_query_vars' );

/**
 * Add new query var.
 *
 * @param array $vars vars.
 *
 * @return array An array of items.
 */
function new_item_query_vars( $vars ) {

    $vars[] = 'narcx-products';
    return $vars;
}


add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'add_new_item_tab' );

/**
 * Add New tab in my account page.
 *
 * @param array $items myaccount Items.
 *
 * @return array Items including New tab.
 */
function add_new_item_tab( $items ) {

    $items['narcx-products'] = 'NarcX Products';
    return $items;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_account_new-item_endpoint', 'add_new_item_content' );

add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode' );
/**
 * Add content to the new tab.
 *
 * @return  string.
 */
function add_new_item_content() {
    echo do_shortcode('[products] ');
}
```

Tried custom endpoint code in my "function.php" file in theme, should be able to remove account data and add products to that endpoint tab in my account page.

Comment: I guess you'll have to work with the actions executed in https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/templates/myaccount/my-account.php then - remove all callbacks that have been added for those two hooks, that create output you don't like.